# Array index out of bound exception java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

The following code throws array index out of bound exception. I have initialized a size of 1000 yet not fully utilized. What exactly are the values of unused indices?

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
     String s="i am a stupid";
     buffer=s.getBytes();

     System.out.println(buffer[30]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call the `String#getBytes`method you get a new array, initialized with the length equals to the number of bytes needed to represent the string. Due to [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the given charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

In your case it's length equals to length the string (13 bytes) and it's less then 30 anyway. That is the reason you get this exception, while trying to get the 30th element.

If you need to initialize your buffer variable with an array you become from string, you need to use [System#arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method:

```
byte[] byteAr = s.getBytes();
System.arraycopy(byteAr, 0, buffer, 0, byteAr.length);
```

If you wish to know, what are values used to initialize an array by default, so it's a default velues for datatype your array consist of. In case of bytes, the default value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Because `buffer=s.getBytes();` doesn't use the array you just allocated. It makes `buffer` reference a completely new array which in your example won't have 30 members.

Answer (score 1):

The `buffer` you allocate is no longer reachable when you reassign the reference. I think you wanted to use [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) like

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
String s="i am a stupid";
byte[] bytes=s.getBytes();
System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, buffer, 0, bytes.length);
```

Note that `buffer[30]` will default to a value of `0`.

Comment: Will this adjust my buffer size to the size of the string in byte array?

Comment: @VishalS no, your buffer size will be 1000, just first elements will be initialized from the string

Comment: I am checking the buffer's size to break out of the while loop in my code(if not 1000, i want to break). In that sense, can i check the length of bytes and buffer mentioned above. B'coz i want to break out if they are not equal.